# Exceptions in C (Try Catch)

Tags: c, exception, try-catch

I'm just asking how to use Try Catch in C. I was searching at Google and I found that C does not support Exceptions but I can use something call setjmp and longjmp, but I  did not understand that. Also, I know how to use exceptions in C++. It'd be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){
   int opc;
   bool aux=true;
   cin.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);
   do{
   try{
       cout<<"PLEASE INSERT VALUE:"<<endl;
       cin>>opc;
       aux=true;

   }
   catch(std::ios_base::failure& fail){
             aux=false;
             cout<<"PLEASE INSERT A VALID VALUE."<<endl;
             cin.clear();
             std::string tmp;
             getline(cin, tmp);
           }
           }while(aux==false);
 system("PAUSE");
}//main
```

**Any help with C?**

Comment: this is C++,note (cout<<).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing in `C`.
As a workaround you may want to:

- Put the code under `try` in a function
- Make the function return an [error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h)
- Analyze the returned code and put what you would have done in `catch` under a condition

Example:

```
int error = my_try();
if(error == ENOMEM)
{
    printf("Out of memory: Abort\n");
    return -1;
}
else if(error == EINVAL)
{
    printf("Invalid parameter\n");
    return -1;
}
// else error == 0: everything went smoothly
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C doesn't support automatic exceptions best practice is to check the return value from any function that may fail. And yes, you usually get to write a lot of error handling code when writing robust programs.

The functions `setjmp`/`longjmp` is support for manual exceptions (similar to `throw` in java) and can be used to reduce the amount of checking necessary.

So, what do I mean when I say that there are no automatic exceptions?
When things go terribly wrong in C the process gets a signal, not an exception. So there are automatic exceptions, only the mechanism is totally different.

This means that in C you still need to check return values from functions like `malloc`, because `setjmp`/`longjmp` won't protect you from the effects of invoking undefined behaviour (like using a null pointer).

Comment: This is wrong. Plain wrong! C supports exceptions through setjmp/longjmp. Using return values to indicate errors is an awful way to make programs complex and difficult to read/refactor.

Comment: @earizon I have elaborated on why you still need to check return values. My experience is that using return values is much more common than using setjmp/longjmp. setjmp/longjmp may look like a neat way to recover from an error deep down in the call stack, but you still need to solve the problem of obtaining the thread-specific environment pointer in that deep down function. And since so many C programmers don't understand setjmp/longjmp, I don't agree that code using setjmp/longjmp is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Lindbâck: "so many C programmers don't understand setjmp/longjmp"
I think this is more a cultural issue than a technical issue. We have tons of GUI libraries solving the same problem (GTK, Qt, OWL, MFC, Quartz,...). On the opposite I wrote to the glib developpers a few years ago to include the libctrans frontend to setjmp/longjmp in the library (or something similar), since I found nothing similar in glib or any other library. They just ignored my proposal and nothing has been developped since then that I'm aware of. The result is a lot of extra work checking return values.